# how to solve css overflow issue without using overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

basically the `body` element has a large amount of extra space on the bottom. but when i inspect `body`, the height is a normal number. so how can i get rid of the extra white space without setting `overflow: hidden` on `body`?

the reason why i dont want to use `overflow: hidden` is that it breaks `$window.on('scroll')` event. is there a way solve conflict between overflow:hidden and jquery window on scroll?

here is the css for html and body. thanks.

```
html, 
body, 
.content-wrap {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[this is the css file relates to this issue i think, the issue is gone without this file](https://github.com/shangsunset/joyceful/blob/master/static/css/offCanvasMenu.css)

[html](https://github.com/shangsunset/joyceful/blob/master/templates/photography/includes/base.html#L46)

sorry the messy files, i dont know of a better way to present my issue here

Comment: Can you post a complete code example so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where this is happening? The extra white space could be caused by any number of things; impossible to guess without seeing in context.

Comment: Why dont you try to remove the 'extra space' instead???

Comment: yea i tried going through each div but didnt find the cause of the white space...

Answer (score 0):

try using this ...

```
html{ position:relative; height:100%; }
body{top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;}
```

this way your html is minimum the height of the window and the body element is forced to fill it... Then just stick header, footer, etc where they need to go.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this but it works.  I use it all the time for this problem.

Comment: well then its something else, can you give a link, or more code?

Comment: yea.. gonna need a live demo to figure out with all those JS libraries.